# Increasing capacity of Micro Cloud Foundry 1.2 in offline mode

Tags: cloud-foundry

I would like to do some real world data testing on micro cloud foundry but the capacity of postgres database is limited to 256MB which is not sufficient for my testing. Is there a way to increase the db capacity temporarily in offline mode for testing?

If not, can somebody point me the latest instructions of setting up private cloud foundry server on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can ssh in to the instance, change the configuration for mysql and restart the service.

SSH to the MCF instance :

```
$ ssh vcap@api.<your-mcf-instance-name-here>.cloudfoundry.me
```

*note - if you can't remember the password for the vcap user, you can change this via the vm console menu by selecting option 3.

Edit the mysql-node configuration file :

```
$ vi /var/vcap/jobs/mysql_node/config/mysql_node.yml
```

the file should look something or exactly like this :

```
---
local_db: sqlite3:/var/vcap/store/mysql_node.db
base_dir: /var/vcap/store/mysql
mbus: nats://nats:f5dc63f74be5e38f@127.0.0.1:4222
index: 0
logging:
  level: debug
  file: /var/vcap/sys/log/mysql_node/mysql_node.log

pid: /var/vcap/sys/run/mysql_node/mysql_node.pid
available_storage: 2048
node_id: mysql_node_1
max_db_size: 256
max_long_query: 3
mysql:
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
  socket: /var/vcap/sys/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  user: root
  pass: dc64fad710976ea5
migration_nfs: /var/vcap/services_migration
max_long_tx: 0
max_user_conns: 20
mysqldump_bin: /var/vcap/packages/mysql/bin/mysqldump
mysql_bin: /var/vcap/packages/mysql/bin/mysql
gzip_bin: /bin/gzip

ip_route: 127.0.0.1

z_interval: 30
max_nats_payload: 1048576
```

The two lines you are interested in are;

```
available_storage: 2048
```

and

```
max_db_size: 256
```

The first line is the maximum available amount of disk storage made available to MySQL, the second is the maximum size per mysql db instance. Set these to your desired values, obviously available_storage has to be large than max_db_size and also a multiple of that value.

Save the file and then restart the VM (shut it down via the menu in the VM console or do it via SSH) and you should be good to go!